# how to place two equations side by side

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I have seen other answers to the same problem but none seem to work for me.
I have this code:

```
\documentclass [10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/franc/OneDrive/Documentos/desISTo/e1}}


\hyphenation{mate-mática recu-perar}

\begin{document}
\section* {Simulação no LTSpice}
\subsection* {4.1 - Ponto de Funcionamento em Repouso}
Fazendo a análise do circuito com uma tensão Vs constante, os andares de amplificação são "isolados" do resto do circuito devido aos condensadores C1 e C2, fazendo com que a única fonte de tensão a alimentar o circuito seja Vcc. Fazendo a simulação do circuito no regime Dc op point no LTSpice, obteve-se os seguintes resultados:
\begin {figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 1.0\textwidth]{Screenshot (277).png}
    \caption{Valores das tensões e correntes nos pontos pedidos.}
\end {figure}

\subsection* {4.2 - Análise AC e determinação das impedâcias Ri1 e Ri2}
Para calcular as impedâncias de entrada de cada um dos transístores, primeiro determinou-se qual a frequência a qual correspondia à voltagem $v_{o1}$ mais alto. Através do cursores observou-se que esta frequência é de aproximadamente 16.8 KHz, a qual originava uma tensão $\approx$ 3.81 V. Todos os cálculos seguintes são realisados nesta frequência.
\[
    \ R_{i1} = \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}}  \approx \text{19.84 K}\Omega 
\]
\[
    \ R_{i2} = \frac{v_{O1}}{i_{B2}}  \approx \text{208.3 K}\Omega 
\]
\end{document}
```

that gives this snippet of the output:
[image]

but I want something like this (arrows are a bonus):
[image]

Any help?

Comment: If you don't want a number for each equation it's easier, just use a \ [ ... \ ] and put the two equations separated by \qquad.

Comment: I would suggest to not include the arrows. Write a complete sentence instead.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this.  I would use \align* with && between the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \implies R_{i1} = \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}}  \approx \text{19.84 K}\Omega
    \qquad
    \implies R_{i2} = \frac{v_{O1}}{i_{B2}}  \approx \text{208.3 K}\Omega
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For writing of quantities I would use `siunitx` package and insert a bit wide distance between equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
    \implies R_{i1} = \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}}  \approx  \qty{19.84}{\kilo\ohm}
    \hspace{5em}
    \implies R_{i2} = \frac{v_{O1}}{i_{B2}}  \approx \qty{ 208.3}{\kilo\ohm}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)